# Serve time/serve their time/serve their sentence in prison

Tags: grammar, collocations

How do you describe colloquially and grammatically a prisoner who is currently in prison.

> - a prisoner who **serves time** in prison
> - a prisoner who **serves their time** in prison
> - a prisoner who **serves their sentence** in prison

Are there any difference? Especially sentence#1 and sentence#2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you first sentence, **serving time** is a common expression.

> He's serving time in prison.
>   He's serving time at the state penitentiary.

The second and third are less common because the phrase *serving time* is generally not broken up by another word when talking about somebody's current state. (It can be broken up and understood, but it doesn't happen as often.)

---

When the phrase *serving time* is broken up, it's normally done when referring to the past or future, rather than the present:

> You've done your crime, now you'll have to serve your time.
>   She committed crimes and served her time for them.

---

So, while there is little difference between your sentences *grammatically*, your first is the most *idiomatic* when it comes to the present—because we commonly don't break up the phrase **serving time**.

Answer (score -2):

Though the first sentence is understood, I have rarely come across such a usage. *If the context is prison or jail,* the commonest expression is telling *what sentence* it is rather than *serving time.*

Check:

> ‘he is serving a ten-year jail sentence’ as in [OxfordDictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/serve)

Or using a direct word - prison

> They are serving prison sentences for their part in the assassination as in [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/prison-sentence).

About sentence two, it's okay as you are using *epicene* or a [*singular they*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they) to refer a neutral gender 'prisoner.*